# Are there any compatibility issues with Canon 60D body and the Canon Speedlite 430EX?

Tags: flash, canon-60d, hotshoe-flash

I have an opportunity to purchase a rarely used Canon Speedlite 430EX flash. I admit I know next to nothing about flashes but want to learn the basics with this one.  I understand that this is an older unit and that a Canon flash should be compatible with lenses and body. I have a "newer" 60D body and Canon lenses. Will there be any compatibility issues?

Comment: I also have this exact combination of flash and camera body and can confirm they work together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. On the [430EX product page](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/support/professional/professional_cameras/flashes/speedlite_430ex#Specifications) it says:

> Compatible Cameras: All Canon EOS cameras...

Compatibility between Speedlites and bodies is very good within the Canon world. You don't always get 100% of all features, but the reason for this is generally obvious. For example, older bodies cannot program the radio trigger in the new 600EX-RT from within the camera's menus. But, you *can* program the optical trigger from the 5D Mk II menus. Further, it works as a normal on-camera flash on any EOS body, and it will work as a radio trigger if you set the triggering up using the on-flash controls.

The other direction — newer body, older Speedlite — tends to work without fuss, too. I've used an ancient 380EX on my 5D Mk II several times, for example. If you go with an old enough flash, like an EZ series, you will lose out on body features like E-TTL, but that should also be unsurprising.

Comment: Note that the OP asks about 430EX and you link to 430EXII. See here: http://usa.canon.com/cusa/support/professional/professional_cameras/flashes/speedlite_430ex#Specifications. While there is no reason to believe there is an incompatibility with the 430EX, it is still a much older model, and their may be some due to the age difference between the flash and the 60D body. I can confirm 380EX compatibility with RebelXT and 7D as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the URL, though it still says the same thing as the other page.

Comment: Yes, it says so, but it *may* be that this text is very old... and was true at the relevant time, but no longer so. Again - i don't think there is a problem, though.

Answer (score 4):

I have used an original 430 on my 60D with no issues including using it as a slave from the built in trigger on the 60D.

Comment: thanks!  I purchased the unit.  Have to read the camera and the flash manual but; I saw a video online where a guy was able to wirelessly fire the 430EX II (new version) from his 7D. Can this be done with the 60D and the 430EX original version?

Comment: @Jakub: Quoting from [this page](http://photonotes.org/articles/eos-flash/index3.html), "Speedlites 420EX, 430EX, 430EX II, 550EX, 580EX, 580EX II can all act as a slave flash when using wireless E-TTL." The new 600EX-RT goes on that list, too, of course. Speedlites not on that list can usually act as non-E-TTL slaves, but to make best use of that capability you want to use it with a unit that has the ability to do manual power adjustment. Otherwise, you have to use ND gels or other trickery to control their flash power.